# ASP.NET5 MVC6 routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following route defined in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "api",
      template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
   );
});
```

And the following controller:

```
public class BookmarksController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetAll()
    {
        return "GetAll Action";
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "Get action";
    }
}
```

Can someone explain please why I **can** invoke `GetAll` Action by api/bookmarks/getall, but **can not** invoke `Get` by api/bookmarks/get/3 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. If you have controllers/actions which are decorated with attribute routes, any request which matches the conventional routes (the ones defined in your Startup.cs) cannot find/reach those controllers/actions. That is the reason `GetAll` can be invoked by using a conventional route where as you should be able to reach the `Get(int id)` by doing the url like `/10` (of course, you migt want to modify this template :-))

Comment: In my example neither class nor actions were decorated with attribute routes and api/bookmarks/get/3 matches the api/{controller}/{action}/{id?} route template.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I think I understand.

To invoke a action method of the Web API it is not necessary to include method name in the URL.

`GetAll()` can be invoked via api/bookmarks/ instead if api/bookmarks/getall
and `Get(int id)` can be invoked via api/bookmarks/3 instead of api/bookmarks/get/3

Comment: Did you use WebCompatShim ? It dosen't look like standart behavior, since you didn't specify Route attribute to your controller. Without it your actions have to be available without `api/bookmarks/`.